# How to convert OrchestrationRuntimeStatus string to int?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core

The orchestrationRuntimeStatus takes the 8 values which are Canceled, Completed, ContinuedAsNew, Failed, Pending, Running, Terminated and unknown which are represented by 4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 0, 5 and -1 respectively. When I checked the returned value of a function whose return type is orchestrationRuntimeStatus, the returned value is coming as Completed, Running etc.... Is there a way to get the same return type where returned value is 1, 0 etc...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.orchestrationruntimestatus?view=azure-dotnet-legacy

Comment: That's an enum, not a string. It's already an integer. If you want to parse a string into the enum, use `Enum.Parse`. Any JSON serializer can handle enums. An enum value can be treated as the underlying integer directly. What does your code look like? What is the actual problem? Why do you think it's a string? Are you trying to use a JSON response without deserializing it?

Comment: When printing the returned output, the values are coming as Completed, Running etc... I want them to come as 1,0 etc... I thought it is easy for the reader to understand my problem if I say string and integer, that is the reason I said string and integer in the question.
 I want my output to appear like 1,0 but not like completed, running. Is there a way to do that? How to deserialize the output?

Comment: Cast the enum to an int before printing it. E.g. `Console.WriteLine((int)orchestrationRuntimeStatus);`

Comment: I don't want to use the cast. I want to deserialize it. How to deserialize it?

Comment: You shouldn't have to anything extra if you use a DTO with the correct type. `I don't want to use the cast.` why not? That enum is *already* an integer. If you store it to an `int` variable it will just work. If you pass it to an `int` parameter it will just work. *Post your code*. You may not have to do anything

Comment: Clearly there isn't enough accurate information in your question for anyone to answer it effectively. Post some code, and describe what actually happens and what you want to happen; then someone might actually be able to answer your question.

Comment: Hey I posted another question with the details, Can you help me there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69525756/orchestrationruntimestatus-enum-serialization-or-deserialization