# OrchestrationRuntimeStatus Enum serialization or deserialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, .net-core

I have this enum

```
 public enum OrchestrationRuntimeStatus
    {
        Unknown = -1,
        Running = 0,
        Completed = 1,
        ContinuedAsNew = 2,
        Failed = 3,
        Canceled = 4,
        Terminated = 5,
        Pending = 6
    }
```

There is a variable in my class **status** of the type **OrchestrationRuntimeStatus**. The variable is

```
public sealed class status
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
            public OrchestrationRuntimeStatus RuntimeStatus { get; set; }
}
```

I have another function whose return type is **OkObjectResultWithHeaders(status, headers)**.

When I see the value of status.RuntimeStatus in the above function it is showing as unknown, running, I want to show it as -1, 0. Is there a way serialize or de-serialize to show those strings as integers?

PS: Feel free to edit the question as I didn't write it correctly.

Comment: If you remove `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` then this should serialise as an int?

Comment: Thank you so much, It is working. You can write the same as the answer for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` preforms the serialisation of the enum to string. Simply removing this will default the serialisation to an int.